# Can I turn off `twoside` for select pages?

Tags: margins, double-sided

I'm using the `report` class with the `twoside` option. I would like to have my title page with equal margins. I know I could do it manually with `geometry`, but I'm curious: Is it possible to switch between two-sided and one-sided layout mid-document?

Comment: Usually not, in the memoir class (which can be used as a drop in replacement for the report class) we have a feature that can calculate the margin adjustment, which can then be fed into the `adjustwith` env (also available from the chngpage package), and in side that environment then the content will now have equal margins). See `\calccentering` in the `memoir` manual. If should be easy enough to copy the code from `memoir` and adapt it to `report`.